# $l_{\infty}$ is isomorphically embedded into dual spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

If $l_{\infty}$ can be embedded isomorphically into a dual space $X^{*}$, that is, there exists an isomorphism from $l_{\infty}$ into $X^{*}$, can $l_{\infty}$ be $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to a subspace of $X^{*}$ for every $\epsilon>0$ ? This result may be already known. Thank you!

Comment: This result  is due to J. R. Partington in  1981. Thank you!

Comment: What you want is easier to prove than Partington's theorem.  If $c_0$ isomorphically embeds into $X^*$ then $c_0$ $(1+\epsilon)$-embeds for every $\epsilon > 0$ by James' theorem. This forces $\ell_1$ to be a   $(1+\epsilon)$-quotient of $X$.